# NSInvalidArgumentException [NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Got the error  `NSInvalidArgumentException [NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (1)`. I used following code for

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
SBJsonParser *parser =  [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:responseData];

paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"json_keys.plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:jsonDictionary, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"json_keys",  nil]];
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", errorDesc);
    [errorDesc release];
}
```

Comment: does `[parser objectWithString:responseData]` returns NSDictionary ?
If not then cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from error message, `[parser objectWithString:responseData]` returns `nil` in this case. So, `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:jsonDictionary, nil]` creates empty array. After that, you are trying to create `NSDictionary`, passing empty array as values and array with `@"json_keys"` string as keys. So, error message is pretty accurate in this case.

Fix for this situation depends on what you are trying to achieve.

You can simply return from your method and don't do anything in case, when `jsonDictionary` is `nil`:

```
// ...
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:responseData];
if (nil == jsonDictionary) {
    return;
}
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// ...
```

Another possibility is storing empty `plistDict` for this case:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
if (nil != jsonDictionary) {
    [plistDict setObject:jsonDictionary forKey:@"json_keys"];
}
```

Of course, you can also find out why `[parser objectWithString:responseData]` returns `nil` and fix that.